# strawberry perl on windows install Prima failed with no tiff.h

Tags: perl, cpan

I use strawberry perl on windows. I tried to install Prima module, running

```
install Prima
```

in CPAN console, I got

```
> img\codec_tiff.c:14:10: fatal error: tiff.h: No such file or directory
> #include <tiff.h>
>           ^~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'img\codec_tiff.o'   KARASIK/Prima-1.53.tar.gz  
> C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK Stopping: 'install' failed for
> 'Prima'. Failed during this command:  KARASIK/Prima-1.53.tar.gz       
> : make NO
```

so finally it failed to install Prima. So what to fix missing tiff.h problem?

**update**
Now I reinstalled the latest strawberry perl version 5.28.1.1
However, installing Prima failed for another reason. Error message as below:

```
dlltool -l blib/arch/auto/Prima/libPrima.a -d Prima.def -D PRIMA.xs.dll blib\arch\auto\Prima\Prima.xs.dll
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e chmod -- 755 blib\arch\auto\Prima\Prima.xs.dll
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e cp -- Prima/VB/VB.pl blib\script\VB.pl
pl2bat.bat blib\script\VB.pl
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pl2bat.bat blib\script\VB.pl, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
gmake: *** [Makefile:1165: blib\script\VB.pl] Error 2
  KARASIK/Prima-1.53.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\gmake.exe -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Prima'.
Failed during this command:
 KARASIK/Prima-1.53.tar.gz                    : make NO
```

And if I run `install Prima` the second time, it shows

```
Running install for module 'Prima'
  KARASIK/Prima-1.53.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\Prima-1.53-0
  KARASIK/Prima-1.53.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
  KARASIK/Prima-1.53.tar.gz
  Could not make: Unknown error
```

What should I do?

Comment: You will need to tell us what version of Strawberry Perl you are using (`perl -V`). See also the [Prima documentation](https://metacpan.org/source/KARASIK/Prima-1.53/README.md) on installation steps. Maybe upgrading your Strawberry Perl version is all that's needed.

Comment: Hi, @Corion  I updated my post. Even latest strawberry perl doesn't work.

Comment: `CreateProcess(NULL, pl2bat.bat blib\script\VB.pl ... failed` - this means that your `PATH` environment was not set up correctly. You can likely force-install Prima at this point or reboot the machine to make sure that the path is set up correctly for the new Strawberry Perl version